# what's the project mgmt stackoverflow site?

Tags: discussion

Isn't there a projmgmtflow.com site, or something?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites

Comment: meta.stackexchange.com would be the correct place to ask this question. Check out the list that fretje linked to.

Comment: Whoa, I thought meta.stackoverflow.com was actually stackexchange.com. thanks for the ptr.

Answer (score 2):

[Ask About Projects](http://www.askaboutprojects.com/) seems to be the most relevant SO-based site for project management.

Comment: bat me to it! I'm active on there as/when questions appear I can participate in